# Loop in custom taxonomy page not picking up any post

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type calles articles and a custom "category like" taxonomy called areas which seem to be working fine. The problem is that in my taxonomy-areas.php page they don't  show up if I use the regular loop, I have to explicitly append "post_type=articles" to the query string for it to work. Shouldn't this be picked up by default?

My taxonomy page looks like this:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; ?>
<?php global $query_string; query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=articles&paged=' . $paged); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   // Handle loop
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: without much code I'm not exactly sure, but any default Wordpress loop assumes post_type=post

Comment: I just edited the post with a sample code, I see what you mean so I have to add the custom post type like I did no matter what? I'm having some pagination problems and I thought that could be the cause

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just fixed it with this: http://walrusinacanoe.com/web-development/742

And removed the 2 extra lines on top of the loop :)

Comment: whats your fix?